# Pushwoosh Android manifest file validation

Tags: android, push-notification, pushwoosh

Currently I am integrating pushwoosh with Native Android application.

I had added the following receiver

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="MY_PROJECT_PACKAGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I have replaced the MY_PROJECT_PACKAGE value to my project's packagename.
Still the validation showing the error that the manifest file missed the receiver.

Comment: Thanks for bug reporting. We fix this issue, your manifest was correct! Also you can contact with Pushwoosh [support team](https://www.pushwoosh.com/contact-us/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi here are the checklist for Android Manifest

1st Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<permission android:name="com.test.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

2nd Activities, Services & Recievers

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.app.MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- **** check from here **** -->

    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview" />
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.test.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.GeoLocationService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.AlarmReceiver" />

    <!-- **** if you are using iBeacons else not needed **** -->

    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:isolatedProcess="false" android:label="iBeacon" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService" />
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor" />
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushBeaconService" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

MY_PROJECT_PACKAGE is normally the bundle name(applicationId) of your project where you can get from `build.gradle(Module:app)` if you are using gradle.

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"  //<-package name here
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

If maven, see
https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android/

I am guessing it is `<groupId>` in the root tag.